# Related Record Flow

Tags: visualforce, lightning, visual-workflow, workflow, record-type

I am working on a flow in which i am creating 2 object records (contact and opportunity). The flow is creating records but they are not related records. how do i link them so that when contact record gets created the related opportunity record gets created as well. TIA

Comment: You first need to insert the parent record, then the child, where you will fill the proper lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

In your flow, while creating the opportunity in the Create Opportunity record element, you need to populate the ContactId with the Id which is created from your Create contacts record element. This will link the opportunity to the contact.

Your flow would be something like below screenshot
[image]

So in the Create Opportunity Record element, you need to map the ContactId in below manner.

[image]

**Please note**, there is no bulkification and exception handling done in the screenshots which I have attached. You would need to handle both of it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How do i add the ID from create record element? I do not have any id in there.